# Nodejs app on aws can not be accessed from browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have hosted my nodejs server on ec2 instance but I can't access it from the browser.

ServerConf.js file Is like this:

```
 server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8443, function () {
            let host = server.address().address;
            let port = server.address().port;
            console.log("\n\n---------------------------- " + moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss') + " ----------------------------\n");
            console.log("[ " + moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss') + " ] " + "Im server running at https://" + host + ':' + port);

        });
```

and it starts and prints

> [ November 3rd, 2021, 01:48:52 ] I'm server running at http://:::8080

now if I try to access it from the browser on port 8080 using server IP it says time out. I examines to run this application on 0.0.0.0 but yet it behaves the same. But when I try to run it on my public IP and port 8080 it says

I have opened port 8080 from the security group.
[Security group setting AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G0Ik.png)

However, if I run the nodejs application on my localhost it works fine on http://localhost:8080
and also if I run the same application on my GoDaddy VPS, it works fine. I think the problem lies in AWS configuration.
please help me out

Comment: Do you have shell access to the ec2? Try to exec this `curl localhost:8080`

Comment: @JRichardsz yeah, i have shell access and when I run this command it works fine, although nodeJS webserver is running on default IP address.